# Postgresql include "optional", nullable foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, null, foreign-keys

So I have a probably stupid problem and I don't even know if I'm trying to solve it the right way, but here it is.

I have a department with several employees, an employee can be assigned to a department but doesn't have to be. I thought of using the department no as foreign key in employee, but what about employees who are not part of a department?
Can I just insert null in the fk column? But I'm wondering if that even works because can't I insert only values that exist in the referenced column?

Here's my relevant code

```
CREATE TABLE department(depno int unique not null,
                        primary key(depno));

CREATE TABLE employee(ID int unique not null, name not null,
                      depno int,
                      primary key(ID))
                      foreign key(depno)
                      references department(depno)
```

I hope this question hasn't been answered a hundred times already and I just haven't found my answer while searching for it for the last two hours. But I just can't seem to find anything about whether this should work or not.

Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much already!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This work in postgresql

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/AAXKIK54090)**

```
CREATE TABLE department(depno int PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE employee(ID int PRIMARY KEY,
                      name text not null,
                      depno int references department(depno)
                      );


INSERT INTO department  VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO department  VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO employee  VALUES (1, 'Jhon Doe', null); -- INSERT OK
INSERT INTO employee  VALUES (2, 'Jane Doe', 3);    -- VIOLATE FK

SELECT * FROM employee;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: BTW: `(depno int unique not null, primary key(depno)` is superfluous, primary key is by the definition `not null` and `unique`, just: `depno int  primary key` is  enough.

Comment: @krokodilko You are right, I fix the employee table but didn't check the department one. Also you can reference the foreign key on the same line you declare the field.

Comment: Also you should use `SERIAL` type for your PK, and let postgres handle the ID.